# How do I remove an upvote?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

I upvoted an answer, then a day later discovered an error in the answer (not linked, want to avoid meta-effect).  I've pointed it out to the answerer in comments, and the answerer acknowledged there's an error.  It hasn't been fixed yet (1 day later, so likely hasn't had time).  I can't remove the upvote because the answer hasn't been edited since my upvote.  Currently it's the highest voted answer...

Is there a better way to get the upvote removed than editing the answer myself?

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no better way.

If you left a comment and you don't want to edit the answer yourself your vote is locked. If the answer is so wrong and the fix isn't obvious from your comments you might consider leaving an answer yourself.

It goes without saying that your answer needs to meet the quality rules. You can clarify that your answer **to the question** is a fix for the other answer (and add attribution if you do) to prevent getting down votes for assumed plagiarism or low quality.

Once the wrong answer is edited conform your bug-fix, you delete your answer and reconsider your vote on the original answer.

Comment: I thought deleting answers increased your risk of getting a ban.

Comment: @BSMP if those answers are down voted, yes. But I assume that someone who is above 3K and capable of pointing out mistakes in other answers and formulating a well thought-out question on meta doesn't run the risk of posting an answer that is so bad causing a flood of down votes leading to a ban when deleted. I didn't say: *burn down that other answer because that OP refuses to fix the stuff and post a crappy answer yourself*. Given the fast amount of users here maybe a moderator can tell if we have one such case ;)

Comment: *I didn't say: burn down that other answer because that OP refuses to fix the stuff and post a crappy answer yourself.* - My comment wasn't an accusation; I just didn't know that deleting answers without down votes didn't have an effect in regards to a ban.

Comment: I didn't read it as an accusation but your comment made me aware of the fact that I'm not clear about that. Let me edit it a little bit to clarify. @BSMP

Comment: It's sometimes hard to read tone and I'm not exactly firing on all cylinders this morning. :)

Comment: @BSMP I tend to be terse in my comments. That will never change I'm afraid, sorry for that. I edited my answer.

Comment: @BSMP: Let's just say that someone with over 100 positively-scored answers seems at very low risk of getting an a-ban.